# Эффект отдаленного фона на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, очень часто замечаю такую фичу на сайтах, что задний фон как-будто находится от пользователя на расстоянии, к примеру http://goldneedle.by/ , таких сайтов большое количество, + картинки на заднем плане меняются (например первая картинка это комната, а уже вторая - кусок швейной машинки). Как добиться такого эффекта. Спасибо!

Comment: parallax effect

Comment: эффект паралакс- это прокрутка по картинке которая ка кб идет задним фоном,
 а сам эффект отдаленности или чтото тпа визуального 3д жффекта это фишка самой картинки

http://goldneedle.by/sitefiles/1/3/01_new.jpg

 вот наприрмер сама картинка смотриться точно так же "отдаленно"

Comment: Ага, я уже начал разбираться в этом эффекте

Comment: Но как сделать так, что бы изображение еще чуть чуть двигалось

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I98ojKzYpew  смотрите видео

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Простой пример:***

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*SECTION*/
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(65, 244, 255, 0.8);  
  line-height: 600px;  
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("http://kerriedorman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/free-office-wallpaper-26001-26685-hd-wallpapers.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.ennomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/innovation-2015-ennomotive.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url("http://d-interventions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/full01.jpg");
}
```

```html
<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
    <div class="container">
   <h1>Perallax Slide-1</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="module content">
    <div class="container">
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="module parallax parallax-2">
    <div class="container">
   <h1>Perallax Slide-2</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="module content">
    <div class="container">
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="module parallax parallax-3">
    <div class="container">
   <h1>Perallax Slide-3</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="module content">
    <div class="container">
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

А здесь можешь найти много для себя вкусного: [**Scroll Magic**](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/)

Comment: Спасибо, а я уже видео начал смотреть с использованием jquery

Comment: Конечно это не паралакс :) все таки без скриптов никуда